# Some translation not work after install module

Tags: magento2

I've translate file .csv and it was worked fine.
After installed a module through composer some words not translate correct !
To explain more, for example "add to cart" was translated perfect to my language but after install it's back to "add to cart".
I've tried to deploy and clear cache but nothing change.
Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Which is the module through composer you mentioned? Probably that module caused this issue.

Where did you put your .csv file to translate these text? I'll help you resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Dear, It's module for local shipping comapny. My translate file in vendor/mageplaza

Comment: You shouldn't edit files in the **vendor** directory directly, because whenever you upgrade modules in that directory, your changes will be lost. vendor/mageplaza is the vendor directory for mageplaza vendor. You should add one more directory path to let me know the module, eg: vendor/mageplaza/module-smtp